# Making tables with Kable, issues with phantomJS install and ghostscript

Tags: r, phantomjs, kable, kableextra

I want to make tables with Kable, but I am **unable to successfully install phantomJS**. I found no detailed/helpful articles on this. The code below is what I have used on a MAC OSx computer to make the tables. Is error after I try to make the table due to no phantomJS installed?

Load packages and make dataframe

```
library(kableExtra)
library(magick)
library(webshot)
library(phantomJS)
Error in library(phantomJS) : there is no package called ‘phantomJS’

df <- data.frame(a=seq(1,16,by=2),b=LETTERS[1:8],x=month.abb[1:8],y=sample(10:20,8,replace=T),z=letters[1:8])
```

Now the code for table creation

```
kable(df, "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("solid", "scale_down")) %>%
  as_image() %>%
  save_kable(file="table.pdf")

Error in save_kable_latex(x, file, latex_header_includes, keep_tex, density) : 
 We hit an error when trying to use magick to read the generated PDF file. You may check your magick installation and try to use magick::image_read to read the PDF file manually. It's also possible that you didn't have ghostscript installed.
```

install phantom
w

```
ebshot::install_phantomjs(force = T)
trying URL 'https://github.com/wch/webshot/releases/download/v0.3.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 18193653 bytes (17.4 MB)
downloaded 17.4 MB

phantomjs has been installed to C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\PhantomJS
> library(phantomJS)
Error in library(phantomJS) : there is no package called ‘phantomJS’

install.packages("phantomjs")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘phantomjs’ is not available for this version of R
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an R package named `phantomJS`. Is there somewhere that you are seeing there is? `phantomjs` is a system dependency, a separate program outside of R, that needs to be installed for parts of `webshot` to work. It looks like the error message says the problem is that `ghostscript` is not installed on your system to view the PDF. it doesn't look like any issue with `phantomjs`

Comment: @MrFlick understandable; do you have any insight into the ghostscript issue?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to convert your table to an image.  What are you trying to accomplish?  The usual way to make tables with `kable()` is to just include them in the `Rmd` or `Rnw` document, so they are processed to HTML or tex (and then to PDF).

Comment: @user2554330 I understand now. I have never used RMD but I tried this and it worked. Many thanks!